# Scully (Puppeteer) can't find browser. But the neigbhor project with the same configs working well

Tags: scully, scullyio, angular-scully

When I copy some Scully boilerplate project, I'm starting to change the name of project, and so on. I don't copy `node-modules` to make copying of project a bit lighter. But after installation of `node_modules`, Scully refuse to work, with error:

```
=================================================================================================
Puppeteer cannot find or launch the browser. (by default chrome)
 Try adding 'puppeteerLaunchOptions: {executablePath: CHROMIUM_PATH}'
 to your scully.*.config.ts file.
Also, this might happen because the default timeout (60 seconds) is to short on this system
this can be fixed by adding the --serverTimeout=x cmd line option.
   (where x = the new timeout in milliseconds)
When this happens in CI/CD you can find some additional information here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
=================================================================================================
```

Answer (score -1):

Dirty solution, just remove `node_modules`, add copy `node_modules` from working project (You can create small project by Scully instructions). Then `npm i` to install rest of modules from your `package.json`.